# C# unity WebClient Request is not working for android build?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webclient

WebClient class is giving different result in Editor and in Android build.

```
    void Start () {
        path = Application.persistentDataPath;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        path = "D:/data";
#endif

        client.DownloadProgressChanged += Progress;
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += Completed;
        client.DownloadFileAsync (new Uri(url), path+"/version");
    }

    public void Progress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Log(e.ProgressPercentage);
    }

    public void Completed(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null || e.Cancelled) {
            Debug.Log(e.Error.Message);
        } 
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Successfully Completed");
        }
    }
```

When run from Unity Editor the file was downloaded fine. But when build for Android it gives a error message as *Name Resolution Failure*.

It gives the same error when there is no Internet Connection when running on Unity Editor. But I get the error message in Android whether the device is connected to internet or not.

Comment: what's the value of `url`?

Comment: It's the string that contains the download URL to a binary file. I don't think it is a problem in the URL because the file is downloading when in unity editor

Comment: ok .. is `D:/data` a folder or the file?

Comment: did you try using [Path.Combine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Path.Combine.html)?

Comment: Its a file named data edit: sorry it's a folder

Comment: No but it is working in the editor... Wait till I build for Android

Comment: No Path.Combine is not working

Comment: Problem was actually not in WebClient class its because my apk didnt have the permission to access internet. I just had to change the Internet Access in Player Settings from auto to require as I was using WebClient instead of WWW class.Thanks derHugo for helping out.